# Mal funcionamiento en aplicación de Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una aplicación en Android Studio para conexión a una base de datos. La aplicación se basa en seleccionar una fecha en un DatePicker y, si en esa fecha hay pacientes, rellenar una tabla con sus datos. La aplicación funciona, y la tabla se rellena, pero sólo si pulso la fecha 2 veces. Quiero decir, en teoría la tabla se tiene que rellenar en cuanto se pulsa la fecha, pero en la primera pulsación sólo se rellena con una línea y la cabecera de la siguiente, mientras que si pulsas dos veces entonces se rellena bien.

Aquí se muestra la primera pulsación (no se ve muy bien debido al tamaño del dispositivo)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí se muestra la segunda pulsación.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código para rellenar la aplicación es el siguiente:

```
@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
    String username = i.getStringExtra("us_usuario");
    String password = i.getStringExtra("us_clave");
    int Año = calendario.getYear();
    int Mes = calendario.getMonth()+1;
    int Dia = calendario.getDayOfMonth();
    String fecha = Año+"-"+Mes+"-"+Dia;
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response){
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                String hora_inicio, hora_fin, fecha, nombre, apellidos, prestacion;
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    hora_inicio = jsonObject.getString("hora_inicio");
                    hora_fin = jsonObject.getString("hora_fin");
                    fecha = jsonObject.getString("fecha");
                    nombre = jsonObject.getString("nombre");
                    apellidos = jsonObject.getString("apellidos");
                    prestacion = jsonObject.getString("prestacion");

                    String[] arrayRespuesta = {hora_inicio, hora_fin, nombre, apellidos, prestacion};

                    int[] comprobarFecha = separarFecha(fecha);
                    TablaPacientes tabla = new TablaPacientes(Usuario.this, tablePaciente);
                    if(comprobarFecha[0] == calendario.getYear() && comprobarFecha[1] == calendario.getMonth()+1 && comprobarFecha[2] == calendario.getDayOfMonth()){
                       //tablePaciente.removeAllViews();
                        tabla.agregarCabecera(R.array.tabla_pacientes);
                        cargarTabla(tabla, arrayRespuesta);
                    }else{
                        tablePaciente.removeAllViews();
                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay pacientes para esta fecha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        t.show();
                    }
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                tablePaciente.removeAllViews();
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay pacientes para esta fecha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
            }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                tablePaciente.removeAllViews();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Usuario.this);
                builder.setMessage("Error de excepción en el array "+e.getLocalizedMessage())
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create().show();
            }
        }
    };
    RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username, password, fecha, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Usuario.this);
    queue.add(registerRequest);
}
```

Aquí mi método cargarTabla:

```
public void cargarTabla(TablaPacientes tabla, String[] array){
    ArrayList<String> elementos = new ArrayList<>();
    elementos.add(array[0]);//horario
    elementos.add(array[2]);//Nombre
    elementos.add(array[3]);//Apellidos
    elementos.add(array[4]);//Tipo Servicio
    tabla.agregarFilaTabla(elementos);
}
```

Y aquí mi método agregarFilaTabla:

```
public void agregarFilaTabla(ArrayList<String> elementos){
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutCelda;
    TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFila = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TableRow fila = new TableRow(actividad);
    fila.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);
    for(int i = 0; i< elementos.size(); i++){
        TextView texto = new TextView(actividad);
        texto.setText(String.valueOf(elementos.get(i)));
        texto.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        layoutCelda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(obtenerAnchoPixelesTexto(texto.getText().toString()), TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        texto.setLayoutParams(layoutCelda);
        fila.addView(texto);
    }
    tabla.addView(fila);
    filas.add(fila);
    FILAS++;
}
```

Se que en la línea tablePaciente.removeAllViews(); borra mi tabla, es decir, que si la tengo ahí sólo me mostrará la segunda consulta (en caso de haberla), pero en teoría si quito esa línea el código debería pasar 2 veces por el if de rellenar la tabla, poniendo las 2 consultas (o las que sean). ¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: Creo que al crear una nueva instancia de la tabla dentro del bucle que lee el JSON se te presenta ese problema: `TablaPacientes tabla = new TablaPacientes(Usuario.this, tablePaciente);` y no sé lo que ocurre tampoco en tu método `cargarTabla`. Me parece que hay un error de lógica en todo eso. Deberías leer el JSON, llenando tu `arrayRespuesta` y cuando hayas leído todo el JSON entonces crear la tabla a partir del contenido de `arrayRespuesta`... tú estás haciendo todo dentro del mismo bucle. A no ser que tampoco `arrayRespuesta` se esté creando con todos los datos que quisieras. Haz log de él.

Comment: Edito la respuesta con el método cargar tabla pero ¿Qué significa lo de haz log de él?

Comment: Que hagas log de `arrayRespuesta` para ver si tiene todos los datos que esperas. Si los tiene todos, entonces lo que tienes que hacer es, al salir de la lectura del JSON, crear tu tabla a partir de ese array que tendrá todos los datos, pero fuera del bucle de lectura del JSON. Tu error de lógica, pienso, es intentar crear una nueva tabla cada vez dentro del bucle. Debes al menos sacar esto del bucle: **`TablaPacientes tabla = new TablaPacientes(Usuario.this, tablePaciente);`**, creando la tabla a llenar antes del `try`.

Comment: ¿Y cómo se hace log de arrayRespuesta?

Comment: Algo como esto: `Log.i("TEST", arrayRespuesta);`, pero no dentro del `try`, sino cuando el array termine de llenarse. Nota: Los `Log` debes quitarlos cuando el programa funcione, son elementos de depuración. Luego para verlos debes ver el apartado `logcat` en Android Studio. **¿Probaste a sacar la declaración de la tabla fuera del bucle y del try**?

Comment: Si, los he sacado y no da nada. El log no se cómo sacarlo fuera del try, porque si lo hago no me reconoce el arrayRespuesta.

Comment: No sé si te das cuenta que estás dentro de un bucle, y que todas las variables que declares así: `String[] arrayRespuesta = {hora_inicio, hora_fin, nombre, apellidos, prestacion};`, cada vez que haya una iteracción del bucle no se guardarán los valores anteriores. Tanto la tabla, como `arrayRespuesta` tienen que ser declarados fuera del bucle, y cuando recorres el bucle lo que debes hacer es añadir cada valor a al array usando `add`. Como lo tienes ahora el array se quedará siempre con un solo valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que tu código tiene varios errores de lógica.

Si he entendido bien, estabas intentando pasar a una tabla los valores cuando la fecha sea igual.

En mi propuesta he sacado toda la lógica de la construcción de la tabla fuera del bucle que lee el JSON. Tampoco lleno `arrayRespuesta` siempre, sino solamente cuando la condición se cumpla.

Fuera del bucle, evalúo si `arrayRespuesta` no está vacío y entonces lleno la tabla. Si el array está vacío entonces muestro un mensaje en la tostadora.

No lo he probado, si he cometido algún error el compilador te lo dirá.

Espero te sirva.

```
@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
    String username = i.getStringExtra("us_usuario");
    String password = i.getStringExtra("us_clave");
    int Año = calendario.getYear();
    int Mes = calendario.getMonth()+1;
    int Dia = calendario.getDayOfMonth();
    String fecha = Año+"-"+Mes+"-"+Dia;
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response){

           ArrayList<String> arrayRespuesta = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                String hora_inicio, hora_fin, fecha, nombre, apellidos, prestacion;
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    hora_inicio = jsonObject.getString("hora_inicio");
                    hora_fin = jsonObject.getString("hora_fin");
                    fecha = jsonObject.getString("fecha");
                    nombre = jsonObject.getString("nombre");
                    apellidos = jsonObject.getString("apellidos");
                    prestacion = jsonObject.getString("prestacion");

                    int[] comprobarFecha = separarFecha(fecha);
                    if(comprobarFecha[0] == calendario.getYear() && comprobarFecha[1] == calendario.getMonth()+1 && comprobarFecha[2] == calendario.getDayOfMonth()){
                        arrayRespuesta.add(hora_inicio);
                        arrayRespuesta.add(hora_fin);
                        arrayRespuesta.add(nombre);
                        arrayRespuesta.add(apellidos);
                        arrayRespuesta.add(prestacion);
                    }

                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                tablePaciente.removeAllViews();
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay pacientes para esta fecha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
            }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                tablePaciente.removeAllViews();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Usuario.this);
                builder.setMessage("Error de excepción en el array "+e.getLocalizedMessage())
                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                        .create().show();
            }


            if(!arrayRespuesta.isEmpty()){
                TablaPacientes tabla = new TablaPacientes(Usuario.this, tablePaciente);
                        tabla.agregarCabecera(R.array.tabla_pacientes);
                        cargarTabla(tabla, arrayRespuesta);
            }else{
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay pacientes para esta fecha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                t.show();
            }

        }
    };
    RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username, password, fecha, responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Usuario.this);
    queue.add(registerRequest);
}
```

Comment: Funciona bien, pero ahora me salen las dos consultas una detrás de otra. ¿Alguna idea sobre cómo alterar el código de cargarTabla para que me vaya haciendo saltos de línea?

Comment: Ummm ahora que lo dices, viendo más de cerca tu método `cargarTabla`, el mismo no parece iterar sobre el array que recibe. Supongo que lo tenías así porque llamabas ese método una y otra vez desde dentro del recorrido del JSON... en realidad toda la lógica del programa estaba montada al revés. Ahora tu método `cargarTabla` debería iterar sobre el array recibido e ir agregando cada fila por cada elemento que haya en el array. Ni siquiera necesitas crear esto: `ArrayList<String> elementos = new ArrayList<>();`, pues los datos los tienes ya en el array que el método recibe como parámetro.

Comment: Si el  método `agregarFilaTabla`  está bien escrito, debería agregarte las diferentes filas del array haciendo simplemente esto: `tabla.agregarFilaTabla(array);`... aquí `array`  es  el array que vino de la lectura del JSON con todos los datos que cumplieron la condición, o sea, el que pasaste desde aquí: `cargarTabla(tabla, arrayRespuesta);`

Comment: Tu método `cargarTabla`  sólo tendría que hacer esto: **`public void cargarTabla(TablaPacientes tabla, ArrayList<String> arrayRespuesta){
    tabla.agregarFilaTabla(arrayRespuesta);
}`**, y si este método `agregarFilaTabla` agregará cada fila del array a la tabla. Todo lo demás es redundante dentro del método, si te fijas bien, ya que estás recibiendo en parámetro los datos que quieres agregar.

Comment: He actualizado mi pregunta con el método agregarFilaTabla. Este método lo saqué de internet y no lo comprendo del todo parece ser, porque no se me ocurre cómo cambiarlo para que me separe el array por filas. ¿Podrías ayudar?

Comment: @G.Corporales creo que tu código necesita una revisión más general. A nivel de rendimiento, creo que sería mejor crear un ListView con varias columnas y luego pasar los datos obtenidos desde el JSON a ese ListView con un Adapter. No es tan complicado, pero ahora mismo no tengo tiempo de explicártelo.